# Test all the combinations out of two type lists

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using Google Test Framework and I have two lists of types for which I need to run the same test suite. I was using the macro `TYPED_TEST_CASE` but the problem here is that it is forced to be used with only one list of types, not two or more.

I need to run this test suite with all the combinations between these two list of types. Is it possible to be done? If the `TYPED_TEST_CASE` macro only accepts one list of types, is it possible to generate this list with all the combinations before, insert them in a list, and then use the one-list-only macro?

Comment: Needs focus and a reproduce-able example of a specific programming problem. I think.

Comment: What do you mean by 'All the combinations between those types'? Do you want your fixture to have 2 template arguments, and have a list for template argument A, and a separate list for template argument B, and to produce a fixture for the cartesian product of all As & Bs?

Comment: @divinas precisely

Comment: It sure is possible, templates are turing-complete ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go. It took as always some meta-magic. To make it fit smoothly to GTest I used `::testing::Types` , now you just pass `cartesian_product` as type parameter to test.
EDIT: since `::testing::Types` is not really variadic I had to make some helpers and conversions:

```
template<class... Args>
struct Types { };

template<class First, class Second>
struct type_pair {
    using first = First;
    using second = Second;
};

template<class TypeList, template <class> class Mapper>
struct meta_map {
    using type = void;
};

template<template <class> class Mapper, class... Args>
struct meta_map<Types<Args...>, Mapper> {
    using type = Types<Mapper<Args>...>;
};

template<class Arg, class TypeList>
struct create_pairs {
    template<class T>
    using make_pair = type_pair<T, Arg>;
    using type = typename meta_map<TypeList, make_pair>::type;
};

template<class List, class... Lists>
struct sum {
    using type = void;
};

template<class... Ts>
struct sum<Types<Ts...>> {
    using type = Types<Ts...>;
};

template<class... T1, class... T2>
struct sum<Types<T1...>, Types<T2...>> {
    using type = typename sum<Types<T1..., T2...>>::type;
};

template<class... T1, class... T2>
struct sum<Types<T1...>, T2...> {
    using type = typename sum<Types<T1...>, typename sum<T2...>::type>::type;
};


template<class List, template <class...> class Reducer>
struct meta_reduce {
    using type = void;
};

template<class... Args, template <class...> class Reducer>
struct meta_reduce<Types<Args...>, Reducer> {
    using type = typename Reducer<Args...>::type;
};

template<class TypeList1, class TypeList2>
struct cartesian_product_helper {
    using type = void;
};

template<class TypeList1, class... Args>
struct cartesian_product_helper<TypeList1, Types<Args...>> {
    using type = typename meta_reduce<Types<typename create_pairs<Args, TypeList1>::type...>, sum>::type;
};

template<class List1, class List2>
using cartesian_product = typename cartesian_product_helper<List1, List2>::type;

template<class TypeList>
struct to_test_types {
    using type = void;
};

template<class... Ts>
struct to_test_types<Types<Ts...>> {
    using type = ::testing::Types<Ts...>;
};

template<class TypeList>
using to_test_types_t = typename to_test_types<TypeList>::type;
```

And usage looks like this:

```
    to_test_types_t<cartesian_product<
      Types<char, bool, unsigned>,
      Types<char, bool>
    >>;
```

Live example:
https://godbolt.org/z/XmyHDT

EDIT: added gtest on the godbolt and it seems to work properly with this code

Comment: I am on GCC 9.2 but this code does not compile for me unfortunately: `error: wrong number of template arguments (100, should be at least 0 using type = typename sum<::testing::Types< T1..., T2... > >::type;`

Comment: @nyarlathotep108  I updated it a bit, but still can't reproduce your problem

Comment: still having the same problem. Yes I am using them as in your example. Might be that in CE it works because you are not using the real ::testing::Types from GTest. One difference is that the one from GTest is not variadic, but I do not really know the cause of it.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 If types is not variadic it makes some sense, probably there are unused placeholders. I'll look into it

Comment: I tried to use `cartesian_product` with `std::tuple` instead of `::testing::Types`. This time around it compiles, but in some combination the pair seems to have `void`, not sure why, and with `void` my code will not work.

Comment: In order to work with the `TYPED_TEST_CASE` macro, the output needs to be `::testing::Types`. `TYPED_TEST_CASE` will not work with `std::tuple`. It could also take a `::testing::Types` of `std::pair`, that won't matter. On the other hand, the input to `cartesian_product` needs to be variadic, and I think `std::tuple` could do somehow the job.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 what you can do is use your own variadic type up to `cartesian_product` and then convert it to `::testing::Types<pair>`. If you don't know how to do it I can add code

Comment: I think I do not know how to do it -_-'

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 updated code and example. Hopefuly now it works ;)

Comment: it works, the only things I changed for making in shorter is to use `std::tuple` instead of defining `Types`, to use `std::pair` instead of definig `type_pair`, and I changed `sum` so that it redirects to `std::tuple_cat` which is less code.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 yeah, that's good idea, will fix it when have some spare time